# Ninject mvc InRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject.web.mvc

I use ninject from NuGet with an MVC 4 application

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
```

I know I could have used a ninject class as bas class, but I did not.

In my global.asax.cs I

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

where

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory  {
    private IKernel _ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory() {
        _ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    public T GetInstance<T>() {
        return _ninjectKernel.Get<T>();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController)_ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings() {
        _ninjectKernel.Bind<IVIPRepository>().To<VIPRepository>().InRequestScope().
            WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VIPFullContext"].ConnectionString);
        _ninjectKernel.Bind<IPrezentationProvider>().To<HardPrezProvider.HardPrezentationProvider>().InRequestScope(); ;
    }
}
```

In my web.config I load the module (and check that it is well loaded)

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="OnePerRequestHttpModule" type="Ninject.Web.Common.OnePerRequestHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

My controller derive from `BaseController(IVIPRepository repo)`. And the application runs well... but it seems that the Repositories ( and so the associated context ) are never disposed (breakpoint in the dispose method of the VIPRepository)

I also clear the app_start by removing `NinjectWebCommon.cs` because I think I have correctly setup Ninject.... It seems not.

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you check out this excellent & easy to follow post about Ninject nuget package for MVC 3 / 4: [Implementing Dependency Injection in Asp.NET MVC 4 using NInject DI Container](http://web.archive.org/web/20130824184025/http://dotnetfever.com/implementing-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-ninject-di-container)

With a nuget package, the setup seems so easy that it could be done within 30 seconds.